# Adding Access-Control-Allow-Origin headers to vuejs CLI webpack server

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, vuejs2, vue-cli

Trying to consume public API data from a couple different resources and getting the CORS error: `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8081' is therefore not allowed access.`

Attempting to add custom headers to the dev server in Vus.js cli webpack. I've tried adding

```js
    headers: {
      "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
      "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, PATCH, OPTIONS",
      "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "X-Requested-With, content-type, Authorization"
    },
```

In two files: `/build/webpack.dev.conf.js` in `devServer` object, and also in `/config/index.js` in the `dev` object.

The error persists regardless.

How can I add the headers to the devServer correctly?

Comment: If *"public api"* means third party then you are misunderstanding how CORS works

Comment: I guess you mean basically what I'm doing here is allowing other browsers to connect to my server? So in order to connect to an API that doesn't allow CORS do I need to connect through back end / server? Or...?

Comment: Yes...that is basically correct

Answer (score 3):

I know this is a bit late, but if anyone else is curious, the solution can be found in the [Vue cli documentation](https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#configurewebpack):

> "If the value [of configureWebpack] is an Object, it will be merged into the final config using webpack-merge."

So, in your vue.config.js file, you can include this object with the key [devServer](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserver), which is a set of options picked up by webpack-dev-server:

vue.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
  configureWebpack: {        
    devServer: {
      headers: {
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'            
      }
    }
  },
  someOtherConfigStuff: someOtherConfigStuffValues,      
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is the server side problem. It should be solved in the server. I have primarily worked with Tomcat server. So, this is a problem I see in frequently.

If you use curl or something like POSTMAN and make the API request and you get a good response, then it means that it is definitely something you need to add in API server side, not Vue side.

Otherwise, double check the request that you are sending.